# Passing a variable from TeX to R in knitr

Tags: r, knitr

I want to use a variable that I define in TeX using `\newcommand{}` in the R code.

Suppose I define following variables:

```
\newcommand{\CourseCode}{MTH 123}
\newcommand{\CourseSemester}{Fall}
\newcommand{\CourseYear}{2015}
```

Later in the document I want to write this:

```
Please name your assignments as:
\path{MTH123_FS15_A1_FirstName_LastName}
```

But I want to this programmatically:

```
\path{\CourseCode{}_\CourseSemester{}\CourseYear{}_A1_FirstName_LastName}
```

But this is not exactly what I want. In R, supposing that I pass the variables from TeX to R, I can do it as:

```
\path{\Sexpr{paste0(gsub("[[:blank:]]", "", CourseCodeR), "_",
                         substr(CourseSemesterR, 1, 1), "S", 
                         CourseYearR %% 100)}_A1_FirstName_LastName}
```

But, how can I pass a variable from TeX to R? `CourseYearR <- \CourseYear{}`?

I know the easier way to do it is to define the variables in R at the first place but suppose I can't do that.

Comment: You are correct -- R or knitr does not understand LaTeX variables.

Comment: Good to know, I'll look for other solutions. Thanks.